# Boost scoped lock assert fails

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I'm using Boost 1.41 in a linux app that receives data on one thread and sticks it in a queue, another thread pops it off the queue and processes it. To make it thread safe I'm using scoped locks.

My problem is that very infrequently the lock function fails in the read function with the message:

void boost::mutex::lock() Assertion '!pthread_mutext_lock(&m)' failed

It is very infrequent, on last run, it took 36 hours (~425M transactions) before it failed. The read and write functions are listed below, its always in the read function that the Assert arises

**Write to queue**

```
 void PacketForwarder::Enqueue(const byte_string& newPacket, long sequenceId)
 {
    try
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock theScopedLock(pktQueueLock);
        queueItem itm(newPacket,sequenceId);
        packetQueue.push(itm);

        if (IsConnecting() && packetQueue.size() > MaximumQueueSize)
        {
            // Reached maximum queue size while client unavailable; popping.
            packetQueue.pop();
        }
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << name << " Exception was caught:" << std::endl;
    }
 }
```

**Read from queue**

```
while ( shouldRun )
{
    try
    {
        if (clientSetsHaveChanged)
        {
            tryConnect();
        }

        size_t size = packetQueue.size();
        if (size > 0)
        {
            byte_string packet;
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock theQLock(pktQueueLock);
            queueItem itm = packetQueue.front();
            packet = itm.data;
            packetQueue.pop();

            BytesSent += packet.size();

            trySend(packet);   
        }
        else
        {
            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(50));
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        cout << name << " Other exception in send packet" << endl;
    }
```

I've googled and found a few problems when destroying scoped_locks but nothing on failing to get a lock. I have also had a search through boost release notes and Trac logs to see if this has been identified as an issue by anyone else. I thought my code was about as simple as it gets but obviously something is up. Any thoughts?
TIA
Paul

Comment: Two things: 1) boost 1.41 is pretty old, you might want to see if an update solves the problem; 2) you could modify the area that has the assert to also log the value returned from `pthread_mutex_lock()` which might give a clue to the problem.

Comment: Is there only one global `pktQueueLock`?  Also, is it safe to call `packetQueue.size()` while not holding the `pktQueueLock`?

Comment: Probably unrelated to your problem, your code also seems to hold the lock for operations that shouldn't need the lock, such as `queueItem itm(newPacket,sequenceId)` in the writer and `trySend(packet);` in the reader (unless there are multiple reader threads and the sends need to occur in order).

Comment: If the lock protects the packet queue, why do you call `packetQueue.size()` without holding the lock? And why do you call `trySend(packet)` with the lock?

Answer (score 0):

There is one thread-safety issue in your program, in this piece of code:

```
    size_t size = packetQueue.size();
    if (size > 0)
    {
        byte_string packet;
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock theQLock(pktQueueLock);
        queueItem itm = packetQueue.front();
        packet = itm.data;
        packetQueue.pop();
        // ...
    }
```

The issue here is that between the time you checked the queue size and the time you got the lock some other reader thread might take the last item out of the queue, which will cause `front()` and `pop()` to fail. Unless you have only one reader thread, you need the size check to be under the lock as well.

I do not know if this is the reason of the assertion failure though. The assertion means the call to `pthread_mutex_lock` returned a non-zero value signaling an error. Unfortunately, Boost does not show which exactly of [possible `pthread_mutex_lock` errors](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html) has happened.

Comment: Also, because the `packetQueue` size is changed in the writer thread. reading the size without holding the mutex is likely a data race (and therefore undefined behavior) unless the `size()` function handles the concurrency issues internally.

Comment: I was initially suspicious of this but on checking there is only ever 1 writer and 1 reader so I don't think this is the issue.